# render Grails tag in controller

Tags: grails, controller, gsp

I've to render a select when calling a controller function.

```
class FormController {
    def document() {
        render """<g:select name="tipo" from="${['','one','two']}" />"""
    }
}
```

it doesn't work.. In the html appear nothing when I replace a div with this function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [tag as method call](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#tagsAsMethodCalls) syntax instead:

```
render g.select(name:"tipo" from:['','one','two'])
```

Comment: Thanks: `render(text:g.select(name:"tipo" from:['','one','two']))`

Answer (score 0):

```
//Build your output string as the next:
def output = g.select(name:"tipo" from:['','one','two'])
//And add any other string or tag if you need
output = "Tipo: " + output
render (text: output)
```